# Accessing fields of Tuples

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I have the following pig Script:
My file 1.txt has
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4

```
grunt> A = load '1.txt' using PigStorage(' ') as (a:chararray,b:int);  
grunt> B = foreach A generate A.a;  
grunt> dump B;
```

It gives me the following error

ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (A,1), 2nd :(B,2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to reference `a` as `A.a`. Try this instead:

```
grunt> A = load '1.txt' using PigStorage(' ') as (a:chararray,b:int);  
grunt> B = foreach A generate a;  
grunt> dump B;
```

`C.x` is for grabbing a "column" out of a bag. Say `C` is a bag of items, then `C.x` will create a new bag of all of the `x`'s in that bag. That's not what you want here. The `foreach` is iterating through the bag here for you.